# JS register form validation store locally

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, validation

I created a JS validation for registration form. I wish to store 5 entries locally and while login, those needs to be accessed and validated. I want to create with Javascript, is it possible??

Here is my code:

```
<form name="RegistrationForm" method="post" onsubmit = " return 
 validateAndStoreRegisterForm()">

        <label class="Name">Name</label>
        <input class="NameBox" id="name" type="text" />
        <br />
        <label class="Sex">Gender</label>
        <label class="Male">Male</label>
        <input class="MaleBox" id="male" name="gender" type="radio"  value="Male"  />
        <label class="Female">Female</label>
        <input class="FemaleBox" id="female" name="gender" type="radio"  value="Female"  />
        <br />
        <label id="Contact" >Contact</label>
        <input class="ContactBox" id="contact" name="contact" type="text" />
        <br />
        <label id="MailId" >Mail Id</label>
        <input class="IdBox" id="email" name="email" type="text" />
        <br />
        <label id="RegisterPassword" >Password</label>
        <input class="PasswordBox" id="rgstrpassword" name ="rgstrpassword" 
        type="password" />
        <br />
        <label id="CreateAccount"><input type="submit" value="Create My 
         Account" /></label>

         </form>
```

Comment: When you say "*I wish to store 5 entries locally and while login, those needs to be accessed and validated*", can you please elaborate on that? I'm rather confused as to what you're actually trying to achieve... You're asking how to store variables which correspond to your `<input>` values?

Comment: Thank you for the reply...

i have started creating a application, for login and register i am using javascript. i am able to do validation in Register Page. Here I wish to save the registered entries in local storage (not with DB). And While logging in i want to validate and give login access. 

need to know how to create an array with all the fields saved dynamically.